# How to perform PTZ programmatically for Axis Camera Control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ip-camera

Here I get an IP camera from Axis 
and Axis camera control showing the live view in my Winform program.

I am now going to write mouse dragging and scrolling event 
to perform Pan–tilt–zoom(PTZ) in the C# Program.

However, I can't find any answer 
even though I have been read all the manuals from Axis 
and searching quite a lot in Google.
(Adding a param continuouszoommove in the Url is not working.)

Please help. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out the answer today, it takes me two days for searching..

And here you get the answer:

```
viewer.PTZControlURL = "http://{{ipaddress}}/axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi";
viewer.EnableAreaZoom = true;
viewer.OneClicllkZoom = true;
viewer.UIMode = "ptz-user-setting"
```

For the option of UIMode:

http://wiki.cinemaronline.com/index.php?title=Axis_Client_Side_ActiveX_Streaming_Video_Window

Alternatively, you can add some event like KeyUp/KeyDown to customize your camera control by adding params: pan, tilt and zoom.

Read the manual below about the params:

http://www.axis.com/files/manuals/vapix_ptz_52933_en_1307.pdf

Comment: Both link are broken.